# Нужна ли запятая после «ни в чем»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Есть такое предложение.

*Он не пытался превзойти друга **ни в чем,** серьезнее игры в шахматы*.

Я считаю, что запятая здесь не нужна, автор считает, что нужна.
Хотелось бы узнать ваше мнение — права я или нет? Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Серьезнее игры в шахматы" — определение, относящееся к предыдущему слову, как в строчке "Под ним струя светлей лазури". Запятая перед ним не нужна. В некоторых других случаях она бы ставилась: "ни в чем, что серьезнее игры в шахматы" (относительное местоимение *что*) или "ни в чем важном, серьезнее игры в шахматы" (сравнение в значении уточнения). Но здесь таких причин нет.

Конкретное правило на этот счет [есть у Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108#ppp_2) только для сложной формы сравнительной степени: "ни в чем более серьезном, чем игра в шахматы".